# Rendering a Twig template to string, adding custom asset path

Tags: image, symfony, twig, assets

Our project allows the users to create custom theme files. Because of the way the project is structured, we have to render these files and save the output. The project uses Symfony2.

In order to render this Twig template and save the output to another file, I use a service which takes @templating as its argument.

The services.yml defines the service like this:

```
    theme_renderer:
  class: ApiBundle\Service\ThemeRenderer
  arguments: [ @templating ]
```

This gives me a TwigEngine object that I can use like this:

```
public function __construct(TwigEngine $templateEngine) {
    $this->templateEngine = $templateEngine;
}

public function renderTheme($filePath, $themeSettings) {
    ...
    $renderedFileContents = $this->templateEngine->render($sourceFilePath, $themeSettings);
    ...
}
```

This works fine.

However, if the template contains an {{ asset('images', 'some_image') }} tag, the rendering fails. The exception is:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("There is no "some_image" asset package.") in "<template_file_path_here>" at line 2
```

I need to be able to give a custom (CDN actually) URL for the rendering of the asset() tag. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How it fails? Can you provide more information?

Comment: You should add more information like service definition, Symfony version and error itself (exception maybe).

Comment: @kba I have added the relevant exception and the service definition. Symfony version is 2.6.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think exception message `There is no "some_image" asset package.` is clear. Second argument of `asset` function is package name. Packages for templating component are defined under `framework.templating` key in Symfony configuration (etc. config.yml).

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#packages

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    # ...
    templating:
        packages:
            avatars:
                base_urls: 'http://static_cdn.example.com/avatars'
```

Then you can use `asset('my_image.jpg', 'avatars')`. So, I suppose you have not defined package `some_image` or configured it improperly.